# error while updating in linu terminal ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, sudo, apt-get

I tried to update in **linux** ubuntu using the traditional command in it's cmd

```
sudo apt-get update
```

But when ever i try it it always return with so many errors and no update is done:

```
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease
403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease
403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease           
403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu artful InRelease         
500  Operation not permitted
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease
500  Operation not permitted [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful     
/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-updates  
/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-
backports/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-security
/InRelease  500  Operation not permitted [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu/dists
/artful/InRelease  500  Operation not permitted
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones
used instead.
```

now i have already tried to use this command

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

As well as removing ppa's and getting something new.
i would really appreciate if anyone could help me.
Thanks in advance.

That is the output when i typed/

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

---

```
 GNU nano 2.8.6             File: /etc/apt/sources.list                        

      # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 17.10 _Artful Aardvark_ - Release amd64   (20180105.1)]/ artf$

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates universe
                               [ Read 51 lines ]
^G Get Help  ^O Write Out ^W Where Is  ^K Cut Text  ^J Justify   ^C Cur Pos
^X Exit      ^R Read File ^\ Replace   ^U Uncut Text^T To Spell  ^_ Go To Line
```

Comment: Which version of ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 @nmn

Comment: please post the content of /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: i have updated the content of the questio check it, after trying the command sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: @nmn i have posted the content of /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: Please check this  https://askubuntu.com/questions/999856/apt-get-update-fails-when-updating-from-17-04-to-17-10-after-eol-none-of-the-mi?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa